# Android application login

Tags: android, authentication

Can somebody help me in suggesting some good tutorial where I can start. 
I want to build a simple application with a dashboard and a login screen. For the first time user is asked for a log-in screen. login check is carried out via a POST call to a remote PHP script. Once the user is logged in he/she should be redirected to dashboard. Once the user closes and reopens the application he'she should be redirected to login screen.

i know how to create forms and how to post, help is needed in the area of switching layouts based on user roles and how to import/extend classes, for example I prefer to have a separate log in (activity) class. but this login class need to be imported to Main (main should extend Activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question fully but when it comes to starting and finishing Activities this tutorial is very good:

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=302

If you want the user to be, as you call it, re-directed to the login screen when returning to the app after having had it in the background on solution is to catch the onStop() event in your Main activity. This event is fired when the user leaves the application.

If you explain the line "but this login class need to be imported to Main" further I might be able to answer that question as well.

Comment: only thing i mean is login class need to be written as a separate file

Comment: The whole idea of the android api is to separate all views into different activities. So for you app you probably want the Log in screen as one class (extending the Activity class) and your Main screen as another class (also extending the Activity class). When login is successful you fire up your main activity from your login activity using startActivity() or startActivityForResult() as explained in the developerlife tutorial.

Answer (score 19):

this article will hepls you creating screen
[Android Login and Registration Screen Design](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/)

Also tutorial about [Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

Answer (score 2):

I've created an SDK for [UserApp](https://www.userapp.io/) that takes care most of the user authentication, such as login, signup, sessions, user profiles, social login, etc.

https://github.com/userapp-io/userapp-android

Since it's open-source, you could modify it after your own needs and to connect to your own services.

The login form would be placed within a Fragment that extends the `AuthFragment`, like this:

```
public class LoginFragment extends AuthFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);

        // Setup the login form with bindings to UserApp
        super.setupLoginForm(view, R.id.login, R.id.password, R.id.login_button);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean onLoginStart(String login, String password, Boolean isSocialLogin) {
        // Show loader when waiting for server
        getView().findViewById(R.id.login_form).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getView().findViewById(R.id.login_status).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Return true to complete the login
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginCompleted(Boolean authenticated, Exception exception) {
        // Hide the loader
        getView().findViewById(R.id.login_form).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getView().findViewById(R.id.login_status).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (exception != null) {
            // Show an error message
            ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.error_text)).setText(exception.getMessage());
        } else {
            // Clear the message
            ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.error_text)).setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

And the layout for the `LoginFragment` would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Progress -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_status_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/login_progress_signing_in"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Login form -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="@string/username"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:text="@string/login" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/facebook_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:text="@string/facebook_login" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/show_signup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:text="@string/signup" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/error_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then add it to your Main activity's layout, along with another Fragment that contains your "dashboard":

```
<RelativeLayout ... >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.example.demo.LoginFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

This just showed briefly how the library could be used. See the documentation for more information on how to use it. Also take a look at the demo app on GitHub.

As mentioned in the accepted answer; to log out the user when the app is closed, listen on the `onStop()` event in your Main activity and call `session.logout()`, like this:

```
UserApp.Session session;
session.logout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Login Screen Activity is here

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DemoApp demoApp;
private EditText edtEmail, edtPassword;
private Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    initComponent();
    setComponent();
}

private void initComponent() {
    demoApp = (DemoApp) this.getApplicationContext();
    edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_email);
    edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

    btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign);
    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up);
}

private void setComponent() {
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = edtEmail.getText().toString();
            String pass = edtPassword.getText().toString();
            if (validate(email, pass)) {
                if (demoApp.getSqliteHelper().login(new User(null, null, email, pass))) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successfully Logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Failed to log in , please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }
    });

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private boolean validate(String email, String pass) {
    if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter valid email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else if (pass.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter valid password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else if (pass.length() < 5) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password is to short!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return true;
}
```

}