# How to place Login activity and Google Map Activity in one Application

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-api

I am trying to develop application using Google Maps.. that was ok.. I understood the basics with great examples I found.. but the thing is .. I want to add Login Functionality before see the Maps.. Is that possible.. If possible, please give me an Idea..

My Requirement is First Activity Login - after Login Second Activity is Using GPS find the current location.

How can i place those to activities in one application and how to compile.

Comment: The Person who Down Voted may be Mad Cow....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy, you just need to declare your two activities in your AndroidManifest file, something like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```

The activity that will start when the application is launched is LoginActivity. There is where you have to handle all the login logic. Once the user is logged you simply launch the new activity with this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MapViewActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i understood that... but how to compile that code.. can i compile login activity with Google API

Answer (score 0):

there is no rules or orders to see the map first 
you can use a first activity that you can ask a user to login after that
if the login is matches of the data (db,xml,file) you can call the second activity joined with the map .
if you want i can creat you an example , but not now

Answer (score 0):

Set in your Android manifest file the two activities. As the starting activity set your Login activity where you implement a login code. Then if the login is successful open the map activity. Check this http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/06/send-data-to-another-activity-simple.html

and this

[Android application login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202165/android-application-login)